# QueryPath selector fails with chained :has():contains()

Tags: php, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, querypath

The following CSS selector works in jQuery so I was expecting it to work in QueryPath 3.0.0, but it only returns an empty value:

```
div#caption:has(h2):contains('Product Description') div:first
```

Here is what I am trying to get it to retrieve:

```
<div id="caption"><h2>Product Description</h2><div>Text I want to capture is here.</div><div>I don't want this text.</div><br clear="all" /></div>
```

What is wrong with the selector?

Comment: That's not a valid CSS selector. `:has()`, `:contains()` and `:first` are all specific to jQuery. It probably depends on whether QueryPath uses jQuery selectors or CSS selectors.

Comment: @BoltClock :has(), :contains() and :first all work in QueryPath under most circumstances. Don't know why they don't in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason for this.

`:contains()` treats the parenthesis as string delimiters, so you don't need quotes around the string.

If you wrap the string in quotes, QueryPath looks for the quotes.

For example, `:contains('Subject')` only matches the pcdata `<element>'subject'</element>`.

Just needed to leave the single quotes off and do it like `:contains(Product Description)`.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/devel-querypath/pupZjpTKyOI

Comment: Wow, that's really weird. I would have expected it to work with or without the quotes, since at the time it was removed from the spec, [it did say to accept either a string or a keyword as an argument](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#content-selectors) - the solution here would actually have been invalid according to the definition at the time. I guess this is what happens when you try to implement a selector that was never fully standardized.

Comment: @BoltClock I suppose so. I just wish it had at least followed the jQuery convention and allowed the quotes as optional. QueryPath has been silent since their site suffered some sort of failure, so no ideas when bug fixes will come around for this.